# Sweet Alert 2 checkbox value conflicting with sweetalert2 confirm value

Tags: jquery, sweetalert2

I am using checkbox in sweetalert2 as:

```
            $(document).on("click", "#deleteUploadedFile", function () {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Are you sure you want to remove selected uploads?',
                    type: 'warning',
                    input: 'checkbox',
                    inputValue: 1,
                    inputPlaceholder:
                        'Delete Permanently',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Remove them!',
                }).then((result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                    if (result.value) {

                        $('#deleteUploadsForm').submit();

                    }
                })
            });
```

With this code, the form is not submitting because of the `result.value` becomes `0` if it isn't checked.

However, if I remove the following 3 options, it works fine.

```
input: 'checkbox',
inputValue: 1,
inputPlaceholder:
 'Delete Permanently',
```

But, I want to sent this checkbox value so that I can either soft delete or force delete the data on the server.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63578p9e/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the following code works for me:

```
if (result.value === 0 || result.value) {
  $('#deleteUploadsForm').submit();
}
```

This is because in the case of clicking on `cancel` and `backdrop`. The `result` returns `dismiss` parameter not the `value` i.e on both case `result.value` is undefined.

```
result.dismiss = "cancel"
result.dismiss = "backdrop"
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1e7snpqb/)

And to append value:

```
let input = $("<input>")
             .attr("type", "hidden")
             .attr("name", "permanent_delete")
             .val(result.value);
$('#deleteUploadsForm').append(input);
```